# If V is a homogeneous function of degree $n$ , how is $\frac{\delta V}{\delta x}$ a homogeneous function of degree $(n-1)$

Tags: partial-derivative, homogeneous-equation

I need to prove the above. I can show it by taking a polynomial $f(x, y, z)$ of degree $n$ as $V$ and $\frac{\delta V}{\delta x}$ will obviously have degree $(n-1)$. But I want to prove it properly, not using examples. I took $V = x^n \phi(\frac{y}{x}, \frac{z}{x})$ .

$\frac{\delta V}{\delta x}$ = $x^n \frac{\delta \phi}{\delta x} + nx^{n-1}\phi$

I don't know how to proceed from here. Any ideas?

Comment: The notation $\frac{\delta V}{\delta x}$ is usually not used in standard mathematical references. What book are you reading?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You mention explicitly that "I want to prove it properly, *not* using examples. But you made an irrelevant instance $V$ using an unknown function $\phi$. Maybe useful for you to write down what "a polynomial $f(x,y,z)$ of degree $n$" means.

Comment: $V$ is a homogeneous function if it can be expressed in the form I've written. $\phi$ is a bivariate function of $\frac{y}{x}$ and $\frac{z}{x}$ , like $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ can be written as $x^2(1+\frac{y^2}{x^2} + \frac{z^2}{x^2})$

Comment: You are making things complicated. The way you write $\phi$ means it is an arbitrary function. But $f$ in the question is a *polynomial* in $x,y,z$.

Comment: The expression, $V=x^n\phi(\frac{y}{x},\frac{z}{x})$ does not make sense unless one writes down the definition for $\phi$. For instance, if $\phi(u,v)=e^{uv}$, then $V$ is not a polynomial at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use definition of derivative, $$\lim_{\delta x \rightarrow 0} \frac{V(x+\delta x) - V(x)}{\delta x}.$$ Expand using Newton's binomium. You should find that the term in $x^n$ cancels but $x^{n-1}$ remains in the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose
$$f(x,y,z)=\sum_{a+b+c=n}{C_{abc}x^ay^bz^c}$$
Then
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\sum_{a+b+c=n,\ a\neq 0}{C_{abc}x^{a-1}y^bz^c}$$
Notice that $(a-1)+b+c=n-1$, so $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is homogeneous of degree $n-1$.